# mat autocomplete not filtering properly in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm customizing angular material select/autocomplete to allow nested dropdowns.

Here, I was trying to search both parent or child values, but it doesn't filtered out.

Also, it should display like Alaska (+2 others).

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-final)

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
    <!-- <input type="text" matInput placeholder="States Group" formControlName="stateGroup" required [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
     <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete"> -->
           <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Select Users" aria-label="Select Users" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="states">
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">

  <!-- <mat-select [formControl]="states" multiple> -->
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{states.value ? states.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="states.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
        (+{{states.value.length - 1}} {{states.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>

  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of stateList">
          <div>
          <mat-checkbox [checked]="group.selected" (change)="toggleParent($event, group)"
            (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                    {{group.letter}}
                </mat-checkbox>
          <button mat-button (click)="expandDocumentTypes(group)">
            <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
          </button>
          </div>  
          <mat-option *ngFor="let name of group.names" [value]="name"
             [ngClass]="isExpandCategory[group.letter] ? 'list-show' : 'list-hide'">
             <mat-checkbox [checked]="group.checked" (change)="toggleSelection($event, name, group)" 
            (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                    {{name.type}}
                </mat-checkbox>
          </mat-option>
  </mat-optgroup>

  <!-- </mat-select> -->
</mat-autocomplete>
     <!-- </mat-autocomplete> -->
</mat-form-field>


export class SelectCustomTriggerExample {
  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

  // stateForm: FormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  //   stateGroup: '',
  // });
  // toppings = new FormControl();
  isExpandCategory: boolean[] = [];
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
  stateRecord:any = [];
  states = new FormControl();

  expandDocumentTypes(group: any) {
    console.log("expanding dropdown", group);
    this.isExpandCategory[group.letter] = !this.isExpandCategory[group.letter];
    // expand only selected parent dropdown category with that childs
  }

toggleSelection(event:any, name: any, group: any) {
  debugger;
  console.log("toggleSelection", name, event.checked, group);
  if(event.checked) {
    console.log("stastateRecordtelist", this.stateRecord);
    this.stateRecord.push(name.type);
    this.states.setValue(this.stateRecord);
    console.log("toggleselection ", this.states.value);
  }
  else {
      this.stateRecord = this.stateRecord.filter((x:any) => x!== name.type);
      console.log("else toggleselection", name, group, this.states.value);
      this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x:any) => x!== name.type));
      console.log("after filter ", this.states.value);
      //this.states.setValue([]);
  }
}

 toggleParent(event: any, group: any) {
    debugger;
    group.checked = event.checked;
    console.log("event", event.checked, "group", group, "states value", this.states.value);
    let states = this.states.value;
    states = states ? states : [];
    if(event.checked) {
      states.push(...group.names.filter((x: any) => !states.includes(x.type)).map((x: any) => x.type))
    } else {
      console.log("else", states);
      group.names.forEach((x: any) => {
          if(states.indexOf(x.type) > -1) {
            states.splice(states.indexOf(x.type), 1)
          }
        });
    }
    this.states.setValue(states);
    console.log("statesvalue", this.states.value);
      if(!event.checked) {
          this.states.setValue(this.states.value.filter((x:any) => !x.includes(group.names)))
        //this.states.setValue([]);
    }
    console.log("final statesvalue", this.states.value);
    this.stateRecord = this.states.value;
  }

  stateList = [
   {
      "letter":"A",
      "checked":false,
      "names":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "type":"Alabama"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "type":"Alaska"
         },
         {
            "id":3,
            "type":"Arizona"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "type":"Arkansas"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "letter":"C",
      "checked":false,
      "names":[
         {
            "id":8,
            "type":"California"
         },
         {
            "id":9,
            "type":"Colorado"
         },
         {
            "id":10,
            "type":"Connecticut"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "letter":"D",
      "checked":false,
      "names":[
         {
            "id":18,
            "type":"Delaware"
         },
         {
            "id":19,
            "type":"Denwer"
         }
      ]
   }
];
}
```

References:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evacck-qubgyy

https://stackblitz.com/angular/eboprqqnooy

Can someone help on this?

Comment: When and where should it display `Alaska (+2 others)`? Once you click on enter key after search?  What should happen with autocomplete if input displays `Alaska (+2 others)` and you put cursor in input?

Comment: After selected the values and enter, it should display first value selected +how many others.. similar to the reference link mentioned.. need to have close icon inside the input box to clear it.

Comment: You should clarify the wanted behavior. The input field is supposed to contain the selected values **and** allow to type a filter for further selections?

Comment: yes absolutely, its a multi select dropdown. users can able to select the values from any child dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is quite complex and requires more clarifications and maybe can be solved by some dedicated library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-autocomplete

But I like that you're moving forward with this custom control step by step and want to have something better than you already implemented.

Let's try to solve two your issues which you pointed out in this question:

### It should filter both parent or child values

Angular material allows us to [define custom filter](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#adding-a-custom-filter). You can use similar logic in your example. Just create an `Observable` which is listener to `FormControl` changes:

```
this.stateGroupOptions$ = this.states.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(EMPTY_STRING),
      ...
      map(value => this._filterGroup(value))
    );
...

private _filterGroup(value: any) {
  if (!this.searching || !value.trim()) {
    return this.stateList;
  }

  value = value.trim().toLowerCase();

  return this.stateList
    .map(group => ({
      ...group,
      names: group.names.filter(item => item.type.toLowerCase().includes(value))
    }))
    .filter(
      group => group.letter.toLowerCase().includes(value) || group.names.length > 0
    );
}
```

and then use it in your options list

```
<mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of stateGroupOptions$ | async">
```

### It should display like `Alaska (+2 others)`.

Again, there is dedicated functionality for this case -
`displayWith` [input property](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#directives)

> `@Input() displayWith: ((value: any) => string) | null`
> Function that maps an option's control value to its display value in the trigger.

**html**

```
<mat-autocomplete ... [displayWith]="displayWith"
```

**ts**

```
displayWith(names: StateName[]) {
  if (!names || !names.length) {
    return "";
  }
  return (
    names[0].type +
    (names.length > 1
      ? ` (+${names.length - 1} ${names.length === 2 ? "other" : "others"})`
      : "")
  );
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-final-nzhhdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts)**

The main trick in this custom implementation is to keep model consistent across different types of data: `string`(when user starts typying), `Array`(when you click on checkbox and update control manually) and `Object`(when you select option from dropdown).

**NOTE:** *you can still optimize it and there are maybe many issue you haven't discovered yet*.

**[Latest version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-final-xxw8es?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts)**

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, but there are some bugs here. Case 1: Search for something eg. Alaska and select checkbox, getting undefined +2 others. Case 2: expand the dropdown of A and select Alaska and Alabama and select parent A checkbox. Getting duplicates here. Can you please help on this?

Comment: @UI_Dev I updated demo. Please take a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-final-nzhhdb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts

Comment: Great! One Last issue, search for something, and select any parent checkbox and clear it, still the respective parent checkbox is still checked. How can we clear it?

Comment: Can you please check it once again. If you search and then click on parent it selects only visible items in that parent. Is it normal behaviour or we should select all items from this parent?

Comment: On Selecting parent dropdown after searching, we need to select all the values inside the parent. Also click on any parent checkbox and clear it. after clearing the values, and click the input box which is showing the parent checkbox clicked. it should clear checkbox selection also.

Comment: Can you try this? one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5mizr-final-final-xxw8es?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219090/discussion-between-ui-dev-and-yurzui).